# Java whitespaces between each caracter in file reading

Tags: java, file, space, readfile

I am currently codding a Java application for me and my friends and I am encoutering a big problem...
When I try to read a txt file, it prints the lines with strange caracters and each caracter is separed by a white space.
I tryed with multiple txt files in different folders and I prints the same thing everytime... (I tryed to make the code with a Scanner and a BufferedReader and it is still the same problem

Here is my code:

```
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(_file));

                String website = "";
                String username = "";
                String password = "";
                int usedTimes = 0;

                String currentLine;
                while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    if(currentLine.startsWith("Web Site")) website = currentLine.split(":")[1];
                    else if(currentLine.startsWith("User Name")) username = currentLine.split(":")[1];
                    else if(currentLine.startsWith("Password")) password = currentLine.split(":")[1];
                    else if(currentLine.startsWith("Password Use Count"))
                    {
                        usedTimes = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(":")[1]);
                        passwords.add(new Password(website, username, password, usedTimes));

                        website = "";
                        username = "";
                        password = "";
                        usedTimes = 0;
                    }
                }
                br.close();
```

Here is an example output: (I cant copy/paste the output so I place a picture)
[image]

So if anyone of you knows the answer, please tell me it would be great !

Thank you really much for reading this until here !
   Julien.

Comment: You have not shown any code that outputs something. Please show us where the output is done.

Comment: Oh yes I just added a system.out.println(currentLine); under the while line

Answer (score 0):

It may be encoding issue. You have to check text file encoding, and then you have to try like this: 
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader("ISO-XXXXX"))

Comment: Oh thanks but I don't understood where i have to place it ? Like that

Comment: BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(_file), new InputStreamReader("ISO-XXXXX"));

Comment: Just replace this with your BufferedReader variable declaration

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(_file), "ISO-XXXXX"));

But don't forget you have firstly to check the encoding of the text file and use it instead of "ISO-XXXXX"